# Update to Navigation Property Not Setting the Forgein Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some older code that was running on Entity Framework 4.0.  I updated the model to the latest and greatest (v6), and in doing so I had to make a few minor changes on how things are being created/injected.  I went from the **Legacy `ObjectContext` model, to the T4 generation model.**

I have been running some tests, and looking at the result, and *most* things are looking great. But I do have a test or two where I update or add a reference to the entity object and then verify that the foreign key has been updated correctly... and long story short, its not.

**For example:**  I fetch an Address and it's missing it's owner so I take an `ApplicationUser` object and set it on the `Address.User` property. Historically this would have updated the `Address.User_ID` to the correct value matching the `ApplicationUser`, but its no longer do this.

Any ideas on why? Is there some setting in the newer EF world that I'm missing?

```
Address.User =  ApplicationUser;
Address.User_ID  (is not updated)
```

**Update:**  If I allow the object to be persisted, it is stored correctly in the database with the proper FK value.

Comment: When you persist the `Address` back to the database, did the UserId column for the `Address` has a `ApplicationUserId` value?

Comment: That's a good question, it fails my validation so it doesn't ever make it into the database. i can attempt to remove the validation and see if it still works correctly. i'll post an update.

Comment: @lll if i bypass my validation it does behave correctly, its just not updating that FK in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set the FK of the `Navigation property` instead of setting the actual object.

Instead of doing this since you are just persisting it to the database and not going to do anything in memory

```
Address.User =  ApplicationUser;
Address.User_ID  (is not updated)
```

to this

```
Address.User_ID  ApplicationUser.Id;
```

Comment: I could do this but i would have to rewrite the application, which is not something im willing to do at this time.

Comment: It's because you changed from `ObjectContext` to `T4 templates`. It was `ObjectContext` which is doing the job for you in setting the FK. I guess you have to update your test.